# Is it a prasal verb, "sail up" ? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

> In 1812, the British navy sailed up the Chesapeake and burned Washington.
>
> > Source : *The Next 100 Years* by George Friedman

What does it mean, "to sail up" ?

I couldn't find it neither in Cambridge Advanced Dictionary nor on https://wordnik.com/

Comment: No: "sail up" is not a verbal idiom. The meaning is entirely predictable from the meanings of the components, "sailed" + "up", where "up" would be understood to mean 'upstream'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a phrasal verb; *up* functions as a preposition here, much like in these sentences:

- The *Mayflower* sailed **across** the ocean.
- The pirates sailed **along** the coast.
- The crew sailed **into** the bay just as the storm rolled in.
- The *Proud Mary* sailed **down** the river.

In Friedman's text, I think the meaning of *up* aligns with preposition Definition 1.2 at [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/up):

> To a higher part of (a river or stream), away from the sea : *Last summer I made a trip up the Amazon basin in Peru.*